# Is it possible to cast an 'assignment by operator' operation?

Tags: c, casting, assignment-operator

For example:

```
int a = 10;
float b 1.5;
a*=b; //"warning C4244: '*=' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data"
```

I want to suppress this warning. Of course, one why is to do so is:

```
a = (int)(a*b);
```

So actually I have two question:

1. Is there a way to keep using the assignment by operator and
   casting it in between?
2. Is there a way I can suppress the warning w/o using casting?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  gcc 4.1.2 with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` gives no warnings.

Comment: @dbush I don't  want to suppress all warnings overwhelmingly

Comment: @Sanich You CANT suppress warnings just for this particular case without using cast or compiler help..

Comment: @UnderDog Can i use cast here?

Comment: @Sanich You already are..

Comment: @Using assinment-by-operator and cast?

Comment: Not the way you want it, no. Why would you want to do that anyway? Using assignment by, and doing assignment, you are not doing any code savings..

Comment: @UnderDog Yeah I know, but it will be easier to read in case you have this: `somePonterToClass->anotherOne->anotherOne = somePonterToClass->anotherOne->anotherOne * scaleFactore;.`

Comment: @UnderDog but it is also a theoretical question....

Comment: Is the question about multiplying by `1.5` or _any_ `float`?

Comment: @dbush: GCC 4.1.2 is hardly cutting edge technology, being most of a decade old (February 2007).  The current version of GCC is 6.1.0 (released April 2016); there were three versions in the 5.x series (April, July, December 2015), and versions 4.2 through 4.9 (with sub-versions) in the 4.x series.  It's past time for an upgrade.  I know that some Linux versions still in use also have GCC 4.1.2 (RHEL 5 is one such, I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep using the assignment by operator and casting it in between?

No.  Anything on the RHS of `a *= b` affects `b` and not the product `a*b`.

> Is there a way I can suppress the warning w/o using casting?

Use a nearest integer function that handles the conversion.  The 2 functions below round to nearest rather than truncate as in `some_int = some_float`.

```
#include <math.h>

// long int lrintf(float x); 
// round their argument to the nearest integer value
// rounding according to the current rounding direction.
int a = 10;
float b = 1.5;
a = lrintf(a * b);

// or

// long int lroundf(float x);
// The lround and llround functions round their argument to the nearest integer value, 
// rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding direction.
```